# In AngularJS how to modify service property from callback inside service itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a factory which does a http call and in the error callback I want to set a property a value, e.g `this.password = null` but `this.password` doesn't point to the password.

On the other hand, when I do the POST the data is sent fine: `password: this.password`

The scope of the password property should be different right? Or I'm missing something else?

```
.factory('LogInService', function($http) {

  return {
    username: null,
    password: null,
    logIn: function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://my-domain/api/signin',
        data: {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        }
      })
      .then(
        function(success){

        },
        function(err){
          // reset password field
          this.password = null;  // <-- not working
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

I could set all properties and methods to a var and then return it, but I'd rather method above. I mean:

```
var myService = {
    // my property and methods...
}

errorCallBack = function(){
  myService.password = null;
}

return myService;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a scoping issue. Should be easy enough to do something like this. As always, untested, but seems like it would work.

```
.factory('LogInService', function($http) {

  return {
    username: null,
    password: null,
    logIn: function() {
      var svc = this; //<----
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://my-domain/api/signin',
        data: {
          username: svc.username, //<---
          password: svc.password  //<---
        }
      })
      .then(
        function(success){

        },
        function(err){
          // reset password field
          svc.password = null;  //<----
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was trying with `var _this = this;` but before the `return`, inside the `logIn` function works. Make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to [learn about `this`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/where-does-this-keyword-come-from).

You could fix your problem using [arrow functions](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-arrow-functions-in-depth), which don't change the meaning of `this`.

You may want to [use Babel](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/universal-react-babel#setting-up-babel) to compile your ES6 code into ES5 so that browsers behave well with your modern codebase.

Comment: Are arrow functions widely supported in the wild?

Comment: Check out this compatibility table: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. You could use Babel or a similar tool to compile arrow functions and other modern syntax into something all browsers understand.

Comment: I will take a look